# Vue 3 render dynamic comment

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs3

How can I properly render a dynamic comment in Vue 3? I tried v-html which is not working in my case, for example, https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddX39.png

```
<template>
  <!-- Method 1: not working properly, https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddX39.png -->
  <template v-html="COMMENT" />

  <!-- Method 2: does not solve the problem, print as string -->
  {{ COMMENT }}

   content here

 <!--[if mso | IE]> </span> <![endif]-->

</template>

<script>
export default {
  setup() {
    const COLOR = "#FF0000";
    const COMMENT = `<!--[if mso | IE]> <span style="background: ${COLOR}"> <![endif]-->`;

    return {
      COMMENT
    }
  }
}
<script>
```

***`<div v-html="">` will not solve the issue, see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWNkP.png***

Comment: This will no solve your problem, but you can investigate. Vue actually exports `Comment` that can be used, but does not allow to pass any text to it.
https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eyJBcHAudnVlIjoiPHNjcmlwdCBzZXR1cD5cbiAgaW1wb3J0IHsgQ29tbWVudCB9IGZyb20gJ3Z1ZSdcbjwvc2NyaXB0PlxuXG48dGVtcGxhdGU+XG4gIDxDb21tZW50IC8+XG48L3RlbXBsYXRlPiIsImltcG9ydC1tYXAuanNvbiI6IntcbiAgXCJpbXBvcnRzXCI6IHtcbiAgICBcInZ1ZVwiOiBcImh0dHBzOi8vc2ZjLnZ1ZWpzLm9yZy92dWUucnVudGltZS5lc20tYnJvd3Nlci5qc1wiXG4gIH1cbn0ifQ==

Answer (score 2):

this works for me.

> ```
> <template>
>   <h1>Dynamic Component</h1>
>   <div v-html="COMMENT"></div>
> </template>
>
> <script>
> export default {
>   setup() {
>     const COLOR = "#FF0000";
>     const COMMENT = `<span style="background: ${COLOR}">Comment</span>`;
>     return {
>       COMMENT,
>     };
>   },
> };
> </script>
> ```

Comment: div will not solve this issue, see there is a closing tag inside another comment: https://i.imgur.com/6tqaQAe.png

Comment: @DelowarHosain in order to get help don't try to downvote answers because this discourage people to help you

Answer (score 1):

Create a component `Comment.vue` that uses render function to create a comment

```
<script>
  import { createCommentVNode } from 'vue'
  export default {
    props: ['content'],
    setup(props) {
      return () => createCommentVNode(props.content || '')
    }
  }
</script>
```

Usage:

```
<script setup>
  import Comment from "@/components/Comment.vue";
</script>

<template>
  <Comment content="Hi, I'm just a comment!"/>
</template>
```

Rendered comment:

`<!--Hi, I'm just a comment!-->`

The vue internal api is not designed for these kinda hacks. So, please use carefully.

Answer (score 0):

The `v-html` should be mounted in real html tag not the virtual `template` :

```
  <div v-html="COMMENT" ></div>
```

You could see the comment inside the inspected DOM

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I need to print it directly without any tags. I've updated my code so that you can understand the usecase.

Comment: it's html comment it couldn't be shown in  page

Comment: that's the problem with this one, https://i.imgur.com/6tqaQAe.png

Comment: your issue is not clear enough, please explain more

Answer (score 0):

You may also use dynamic component with the `<component is>`
[Vue JS Dynamic Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components)

And put all your comment component code in a different file: comment.vue

```
<template>
  <h1>Dynamic Component</h1>
  <component :is='currentComponent'>
</template>

<script>
import CommentComponent from './comment.vue'
export default {
  computed: {
    currentComponent() {
      // do some logic then
      return CommentComponent
    }
  }
};
</script>
```